# Want to run it as time complexity of O(nlgn) but failed

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, combinations

I made a program to solve a problem to find which pair has overlapping number
**Example**:A=[[1,3],[4,5],[2,5],[4,6]] returns [(1,3),(2,4),(2,3),(3,4)]
**This program** return the list of tuples each tuple containing the pair of index whose number between them is common
**Output: In the output numbers are showing indexes but because index starts from 0 so they are index+1**
I made a program of time complexity of O(n^2) which is faster than this program i don,t know where i am wrong to do this

```
def Helper(friends,array,p,q,r):#merge sort algorithm implementation 
    L = array[p:q+1]
    R = array[q+1:r+1]
    idx1 = p
    idx2 = q+1
    i = 0
    j = 0
    #print("L = ",L)
    #print("R = ",R)
    while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
        if L[i][0] in range(R[j][0],R[j][1]+1) or L[i][1] in range(R[j][0],R[j][1]+1):
            if idx1+i+1 != idx2+j+1:
                myTupple = (idx1+i+1,idx2+j+1)
                if myTupple not in friends:
                    friends.append(myTupple)
        i = i +1
        if j >= len(R) and i < len(L):
            j = 0
            i = i + 1
        elif j < len(R) and i >= len(L):
            j = j + 1
            i = 0
def DivideAndConquer(friends,array,p,r):
        if p >= r:
            return
        q = (p+r)//2
        DivideAndConquer(friends,array, p , q)
        DivideAndConquer(friends,array, q+1, r)
        Helper(friends,array,p,q,r)
       # A = [[1,4],[2,5],[7,9],[9,10],[6,10]]

def friendsFaster(Input):
    friends = []
    DivideAndConquer(friends, Input,0, len(Input)-1)
    return friends
```

Comment: You can't. Trivial counter-example: `[[1, 2]] * n`. Generating the output alone will take `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Paul is there any way to improve this code?

Comment: You could still hope for an implementation that is O(n log n + s) where s is the size of the output. (There is such an implementation.)

Comment: @Risen_Star you could start by sorting the input by start-value of the segments and then check for intersections iteratively. Sorting is `O(n log n)` and generating the output can be done in `O(s)`, where `s` is the size of the output (worst case `O(n^2)`). Total would then be `O(n log n + s)`. This is the best you can do in terms of runtime complexity.